# probability generating function of a given discrete R.V. X

Tags: probability

A discrete random variable $X$ has a probability generating function $G(t) = kte^t$. Find the probability $X = 7$.

I can get the value of $k$ as $1/e$ using the fact that $G(1) = 1$.

How do i get the second part or is there an omission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outline:** Your $k$ is correct. Now expand $kte^t$ in a Maclaurin series, read off the coefficient of $t^7$. Note that the Maclaurin series we want is easily obtained from the standard series for $e^t$.